# How to save image after resizing it with WP_Image_Editor_GD::multi_resize method?

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a specific landing page in WordPress and want to optimize images delivery. I've found this class in the documentation and think it's going to do the job: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Image_Editor

But WordPress documentation lacks examples of using a multi_resize method, so I don't know how to save resized images with the desired destination folder and file names.

My test image path is wp-content/themes/mytheme-child/inc/assets/test.png

I want to put resized images to the child directory called "resize" and name them as follows:

```
wp-content/themes/mytheme-child/inc/assets/resize/test_300x.png 
wp-content/themes/mytheme-child/inc/assets/resize/test_400x.png 
wp-content/themes/mytheme-child/inc/assets/resize/test_500x.png
```

etc.

What I've done:

```
<?php
    $assets = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/assets/';
    $cur_img = 'test.png';
    $path_parts = pathinfo( $cur_img );

    if ( !file_exists ( $assets . 'resize/' . $path_parts['filename'] . '_300x' . $path_parts['extension'] ) ) :
        $image_to_resize = wp_get_image_editor( $assets . $cur_img );
        if ( ! is_wp_error( $image_to_resize ) ) {
            $sizes_array = array(
            array ( 'width' => 300, 'height' => NULL, 'crop' => false ),
            array ( 'width' => 350, 'height' => NULL, 'crop' => false ),
            array ( 'width' => 400, 'height' => NULL, 'crop' => false ),
            array ( 'width' => 500, 'height' => NULL, 'crop' => false ),
            array ( 'width' => 600, 'height' => NULL, 'crop' => false ),
            array ( 'width' => 700, 'height' => NULL, 'crop' => false ),
            array ( 'width' => 800, 'height' => NULL, 'crop' => false ),
            array ( 'width' => 900, 'height' => NULL, 'crop' => false ),
            array ( 'width' => 1000, 'height' => NULL, 'crop' => false )
        );

        $image_to_resize->multi_resize( $sizes_array );
    } endif;
?>
```

I expect I should use something like $image_to_resize->save(), but don't know how to set target directory and file names for resized images.

Here's a little more info for clarification of what I'm trying to do:

1. I don't plan on using the WP Media Library from admin. The media files are going to be stored in the child theme folder (so it's more convenient to upload them via FTP than through WP admin)
2. Different images are going to need different ranges of resizing resolutions. One should be 300, 350, ... 1000px wide, other should be 30, 40, ... 150px wide etc.
3. Images should be created only once and then be stored on disk to keep server CPU free of cropping images most of the time.

Comment: is there a reason you do not simply use  `add_image_size()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

Comment: I didn't know about this function. But from reading the documentation I have a vague feeling that it's not exactly what I need. Correct me if I'm wrong. 
Here is some more info about what I'm trying to accomplish and how:  

1. I don't plan on using WP Media Library. The media files are going to be stored in child theme folder (so it's more convenient to upload them via FTP than through WP admin) . 

2. Images are going to need different ranges of resolutions. One should be 300, 350, ... 1000px wide, other should be 30, 40, ... 150px wide etc.

Going to add it to original question